# Can we modify some part of a standard benchmark? Will the results be accepted by the community?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, paper-submission

I am researching on spinlock synchronization method used in parallel applications. Unfortunately most of the standard benchmarks in the parallel computing area use another type of synchronization method called mutex locks. I am thinking to replace mutex locks in these benchmarks with spinlocks and get the results? Will the results be still considered by the scientific community if I inform the modifications done to the benchmarks? Will that be a valid claim? Any pointer in this matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by modifying the benchmark? Usually that would make no sense because you want to make test results comparable. Also spinlocks should perform less optimal compared to mutexes.

Comment: I am trying to measure the performance of my modified spinlock so I needed a benchmark using spinlock. Spinlocks are not always less optimal to mutexes. Sometimes they are more quicker. It depends on how large is your critical section and how much parallel is your hardware. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Don't you need the same benchmark and apply it to a program using your modified spinlock and another one using the mutex? How would changing the benchmark let you compare mutex and spinlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always when using code you do not own, you need to check the licensing terms for the benchmark. Do they prohibit what you want to do?

Assuming that is OK, I would distinguish two uses of a benchmark:

1. Report and publish results as results of the benchmark. That should only be done if you have conformed exactly to all relevant requirements, which will probably prohibit the type of change you want to make.
2. Publish a paper in which you compare and contrast the standard form of the benchmark with your spin-lock variation. You could treat the spin-lock version as a new benchmark based on the standard one, documenting your changes.

I know I would be interested in the results. If the number of threads the hardware can run simultaneously is at least as high as the number of application threads, do we need all the overhead to let a process sleep while waiting rather than just spinning? This sort of question becomes more interesting as hardware improvement becomes more a matter of adding hardware threads than of making each thread run faster.

Comment: It is a very nice point to check the licensing terms of a benchmark. I never thought about this point. It is also very interesting to check the usefulness of spinlocks used in applications running on multi-core processors compared to using mutex locks. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: The usage of spinlocks in userspace application is very less as its performance can get affected due to the Operating System Jitter. This explains why spinlocks are not used in the benchmarks which run in userspace. Mutexlocks are preferred instead of them.

Link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/YTEPa9Qtfv4

But for my unique scenario I need to measure the spinlock performance in userspace and thus I ended up with the question. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 2):

You can always *propose* a new benchmark and demonstrate that it measures what you want. Once you've done that, you can show how your new thing compares. The scientific is not guaranteed to care, but if your methodology is good, it may catch on.